How to avoid slow down over long period in infinite animations of CSS?
I have this CSS code below that triggers animation in a path of a D3 graph.The code likes below
.link {
    stroke-dasharray: 4;
    stroke-dashoffset: 40;
    animation: dash 20s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes dash {
    from {
      stroke-dashoffset: 360;
    }
    to {
      stroke-dashoffset: 40;
    }
 }

Here is a link to the animation https://imgur.com/7D2aaYT
Note: I have an entire graph with multiple paths running animation like above.
As you can see from the css and the video, the animation is continuous in nature. The problem is if left for a very long time say few hours or a day, the animations slow down and the tab becomes little unresponsive. On refreshing the page, it's back to normal. I have also observed that Chrome warns about high memory usage too.
So I looked up online and found a solution that is supposed to allevate the issue to some extent.Here is what I tried
.link {
    stroke-dasharray: 4;
    stroke-dashoffset: 40;
    animation: dash 20s linear infinite;
    /* the transform and will-change properties */
    /* are here to only enable GPU */
    transform: translateZ(0);
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
    -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
    will-change: transform;
}

As you can see, I have added these additional three lines
transform: translateZ(0);
-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
-ms-transform: translateZ(0);
will-change: transform;

But I did not find any noticeable improvement with this solution. The animations slow down after few hours.
What am I doing wrong?

You hand the animation off to CSS. You're doing a simple two-value linear transition. There is nothing you can improve. - Does your page in general use a lot of memory, or is it actually increasing over time? - Browsers may reduce animation priority after longer inactivity like they do when the tab goes into background/you tab away.

Yes when I tab away and come back after few hours or next day (putting the computer to sleep), the animation slows down a lot. In some cases, it almost stops. And if I hover on the tab (in case of Chrome), I can see the memory usage increasing over time.

Then you can report it as a bug in Chrome.
